# meteor cordova build error for ios platform

Tags: ios, cordova, meteor

I am getting the error below when building meteor with ios platform. A few days ago it all worked fine. OS is Sierra 10.12, meteor 1.4.1.3. When I remove the ios platform it builds fine. Android is not added.

I already tried:

- Removed and added ios platform
- Removed .meteor/local

Here is the output from the terminal:

```
Tims-MacBook-Pro:pressIt cmt$ meteor build ../outputPressit --server http://dummy.com

... 

=> Errors executing Cordova commands:                                              

While adding plugin https://github.com/meteor/cordova-plugin-meteor-webapp.git#8bf95eed3f313299fc2de33658866278eea2cdc5 to Cordova project:
Cordova error: Failed to fetch plugin https://github.com/meteor/cordova-plugin-meteor-webapp.git via git.
Either there is a connection problems, or plugin spec is incorrect:
Error: git: Command failed with exit code 128 Error output:
fatal: reference is not a tree: 8bf95eed3f313299fc2de33658866278eea2cdc5
(If the error message contains suggestions for a fix, note that this may not apply to the Meteor integration. You can try running again with the --verbose option to help diagnose the issue.)
```

I also tried the --verbose option and here is some of the output:

```
...
%% Copying splash from /Users/cmt/WebstormProjects/pressIt/.meteor/local/cordova-build/resources/iphone6p_landscape.splash.png to /Users/cmt/WebstormProjects/pressIt/.meteor/local/cordova-build/platforms/ios/pressIt/Images.xcassets/LaunchImage.launchimage/Default-Landscape-736h.png
%% updated project successfully                                                    
%% Executing "after_plugin_add"  hook for all plugins.                             
Adding plugin https://github.com/meteor/cordova-plugin-meteor     weba90-]\m8
-=05643pp.git#8bf95eed3f313299fc2de33658866278eea2cdc5 to Cordova project
%% Executing "before_plugin_add"  hook for all plugins.                            
%% Calling plugman.fetch on plugin "https://github.com/meteor/cordova-plugin-meteor-webapp.git#8bf95eed3f313299fc2de33658866278eea2cdc5"
%% Fetching plugin "https://github.com/meteor/cordova-plugin-meteor-webapp.git" via git clone
%% Running command: git clone https://github.com/meteor/cordova-plugin-meteor-webapp.git /var/folders/p7/s_tltgm15mg63r15wkn1c24c0000gq/T/git/1477224169788
%% Command finished with error code 0: git clone,https://github.com/meteor/cordova-plugin-meteor-webapp.git,/var/folders/p7/s_tltgm15mg63r15wkn1c24c0000gq/T/git/1477224169788
%% Running command: git checkout 8bf95eed3f313299fc2de33658866278eea2cdc5          
%% Command finished with error code 128: git checkout,8bf95eed3f313299fc2de33658866278eea2cdc5
=> Errors executing Cordova commands:                                              

While adding plugin https://github.com/meteor/cordova-plugin-meteor-webapp.git#8bf95eed3f313299fc2de33658866278eea2cdc5 to Cordova project:
Cordova error: Failed to fetch plugin https://github.com/meteor/cordova-plugin-meteor-webapp.git via git.
Either there is a connection problems, or plugin spec is incorrect:
Error: git: Command failed with exit code 128 Error output:
fatal: reference is not a tree: 8bf95eed3f313299fc2de33658866278eea2cdc5
at /Users/cmt/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.4.1_3.1u5hjow++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/lib/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/plugman/fetch.js:88:33
at _rejected
```

Comment: did you had any luck? thanks.

Comment: yes, I resolved it but I am actually not exactly sure what solved it as I made multiple changes. Ultimately, I did: 1. 'meteor add cordova:cordova-plugin-meteor-webapp@1.4.1' and 'install meteor 1.4.2-beta4' to get it all working. The former I believe resolved the issue listed here but again I am not certain. The latter is needed for ios 10 compatibility issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seemed to have been a temporary issue as it got resolved the next day without making related changes.